# Integrate a small PHP server and SQL engine in a C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm making a small web application that uses PHP and mySQL. I'm planning to make a little C# application that uses a WebBrowser component to access the website. However, in the event that the server is unavailable for some reason, I would still like the customers to be able to use it.

Is there a relatively easy way to integrate a small PHP and SQL engine within my C# application, such as if the server is unavailable the application can launch it's own server and log in at localhost? Or would I actually have to code a whole PHP and SQL server?

EDIT:

Just to clarify I bit. My question is actually: Is there a way, through third party plugins or anything else, a way to make my C# application to act both as a PHP server and an SQL server in the event that the remote server is not accessible. IE: if server is inaccessible, start own server and connect to it instead. I know I could install and launch XAMPP for example but I don't want my users to have to launch more than one application as they will most likely be computer illiterate.

Comment: PHP comes with its own internal web server (see the console options) that is suitable for low levels of load, and SQLite3 can be used without a database server. But the PHP engine will not be able to run your C# application.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you mean by the PHP engine won't be able to run my C# application? My C# application will be a desktop application, not a .net. I will look into SQLLite3 though,  thank you!

Comment: Ah right, I thought you were under the impression the PHP server could run a C# web application - I missed the desktop bit! Yes, if that's a desktop app, then it should connect to PHP in console server mode, and a PHP script can be used to connect to SQLite.

Comment: But that means that my users will need to have both PHP and SQLite installed on their computers right? I was actually wondering if there was a way to integrate the PHP and SQL server inside the desktop application. I doubt there's anything built in C# that can do this but perhaps someone out there had coded up their own components or classes? Google wasn't helpful on a first search, perhaps I should dig deaper.

Comment: Yes, they'll need PHP installed, but they won't need SQLite installed - that is built into PHP. You've two approaches: either ask users to install PHP first (on Windows they at least used to offer a wizard-style installer) or install a private copy inside your own installation process. You _may_ need to watch out for licensing issues here, since it is open source, and you'll need to check the legal impact of distributing that as part of (what I assume is) commercial software. There will be _plenty_ on the web about that.

Comment: Thank you for answers halfer! I will look deeper into those licensing issues.

Comment: There's definitely not anything in C# that supports PHP (and I've never used C#). Microsoft have traditionally wanted to sabotage PHP's success in the past, and were previously most unlikely to do anything to support it. The situation is changing _slightly_, since they are working with Zend to improve PHP stability/performance on their OS. However, this is (imo) only a strategy to prevent users jumping ship entirely from Windows Server to Linux - I don't think they actually want to actively support it.